# Proving a binomial expansion inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, binomial-coefficients

I have to prove the following, where $x\geq 1$, $0 < \epsilon< 1$ and $q\in \mathbb{N}$

$$(x + \epsilon)^q  \leq x^{q}(1 + 2^{q}\epsilon)$$

My attempt:

---

We have

$$(x+\epsilon)^q = x^q + \binom{q}{1}x^{q-1}\epsilon + \binom{q}{2}x^{q-2}\epsilon^2 \cdots + \binom{q}{q-1}x\epsilon^{q-1} +\epsilon^q $$

And as $\epsilon <1$ and $q\geq 1$, then $\epsilon^q \leq \epsilon$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
 (x+\epsilon)^q  \leq x^q + \binom{q}{1}x^{q-1}\epsilon + \binom{q}{2}x^{q-2}\epsilon +\cdots + \binom{q}{q-1}x\epsilon +\epsilon 
\end{align}

In other words,

$$(x+\epsilon)^q  \leq x^q +\epsilon\biggl(1+ \binom{q}{1}x^{q-1} + \binom{q}{2}x^{q-2} +\cdots + \binom{q}{q-1}x\biggr)$$

I know that I need to get the sum of the binomial coefficients to get $2^q$ but I can't find a way to deal with the $x$ terms attached to them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is there some restriction on $x$? Cause if you take $x = \epsilon = 1/2$ and $q \geq 2$ then it fails.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, $x\geq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Factorizing the RHS of your last expression by $x^q$ yields
$$x^q +\epsilon\biggl(1+ \binom{q}{1}x^{q-1} + \binom{q}{2}x^{q-2} +\cdots + \binom{q}{q-1}x\biggr)=x^q\left[1+\varepsilon \left(\frac{1}{x^q}+\binom{q}{1}\frac{1}{x}+...+\binom{q}{q-1}\frac{1}{x^{q-1}}\right)\right].$$

Using the fact that $\frac{1}{x^p}\leq 1$ for all $p\in\mathbb N$ allows you to conclude.

Comment: Thanks this helped, but I'm pretty sure to get the sum of binomial coefficients which is $2^q$ I need the $\binom{q}{q}$ term which is not actually being multiplied by $\epsilon$?

Comment: **Hint :** $$\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\binom{q}{k}\leq \sum_{k=0}^q\binom{q}{k}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your time man